# Internet Explorer 6 Script Timeline

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, debugging, add-on

I'm developing a fairly large page with several external javascript files. In IE6, the page hangs for a few seconds just as it's finished loading. I'm not (directly) asking for help debugging this problem, I'm only asking for help finding a tool to help debug this problem.

What I'm looking for is something similar to Chrome Developer Tools's "Timeline" tab. Something that will tell me the run time of my various external scripts (or functions, event handlers, whatever level of granularity is available).

I'd much prefer something that is free, but if that isn't available, I may be convinced to shell out some cash for a little extra quality.

Please keep in mind that I'm looking for tools that will work with Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/application-performance-management-product.aspx) could be what you're looking for.

It's quite complex but integrates well with IE and gives you more data than you could ever use: Number of times functions get called, CPU usage per function, a step-by-step look at the DOM tree being built... It's pretty intense.

Godspeed.

Comment: It seems I will not get a better answer than this. Dynatrace, while thorough, and probably useful for my situation, is simply overkill (and expensive) for my purposes, but it's better than no solution at all.

Comment: Oh There's a free version though: http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/misc/whyfree.aspx

Comment: Well that's just fine then. Just fine. (Or it would be if I could create an account...)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler2](http://www.Fiddler2.com) will work well for tracking all aspects of the load time... unfortunately no pretty timeline chart though.

Comment: Will Fiddler2 track execution time, though? That's the part I'm really worried about.

Comment: Oh, in that case no, just HTTP traffic times/headers/etc.  To be honest though, if you can run the timelines in IE8 (`F12` Dev Tools > Profiler) you should get realistic enough results for how IE behaves... and you can then adjust accordingly. Otherwise you are tweaking for a dead or soon-to-be-dead browser... something I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm dealing with enough of a customer base for IE6 to matter. It sucks, but it's a fact.